# MySQL While Statement throws error and only inserts one record of NULLs

Tags: mysql, while-loop, insert, bulkinsert

I think I'm doing something wrong with writing the **WHILE** statement in the below mysql script.  I've tested each individual component of the below code and everything works in isolation (no errors thrown test output matches expectation), except the WHILE (throws an error and inputs only NULL values and only goes through one iteration of the loop).  I'm following https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html the documented instructions but I seem to be missing something.  What I want to do is insert several records (millions) into this table.  What am I doing wrong?  Why does this WHILE statement not loop and why is it only inserting NULL values?

**The Source**

```
USE wordpress;
SET @i := 0;

WHILE @i < 10 DO
    SET @rand_value = CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*10000) as CHAR);
    SELECT @rand_value as CONCAT('rand_value at ', CAST(@i as CHAR));
    INSERT INTO wp_wpdatatable_1 (jiraissue, assignee, testcasename, description, image, automation, testresult, date, status, priority, os, testtype, location, flavor) 
    VALUES 
    (CONCAT('TEST ISSUE ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('ASSIGNEE ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('TEST CASE NAME ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('DESCRIPTION ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('IMAGE ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('AUTOMATION ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('TESTRESULT ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('DATE ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('STATUS ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('PRIORITY ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('OS ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('TESTTYPE ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('LOCATION ', @rand_value)
    , CONCAT('FLAVOR ', @rand_value));
    SET @i := @i + 1;
END WHILE;
```

**The Output**

```
mysql> source /root/populate_wp_wpdatatable_1.sql
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHILE @i < 10 DO
    SET @rand_value = CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*10000) as CHAR)' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('rand_value at ', CAST(@i as CHAR))' at line 1
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END WHILE' at line 1
```

Something odd is that you can see "1 row affected" in the output.  So it does actually go through ONE iteration of the WHILE Loop, but it only does it once and it only puts in NULL values into the table.  Hopefully someone can spot what I'm missing.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `WHILE` statements can only be used inside stored procedures.

Comment: I guess I could make a SP.  Is there any reason it is like this?  Will there be an issue having this SP insert a few million records?

Comment: Control statements like `WHILE` and `IF` are not SQL queries.

Comment: A SP inserting them is no different from doing it any other way.

Comment: The first `SELECT` is also wrong in general. You can't put an expression in the `AS` part of a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a few things wrong.  First as @Barmar noted, **WHILE** statements only work in stored procedures.  Also as he pointed out, my select was wrong (but also meaningless so I deleted it).  There was one more thing needed though.  Since you have to create a stored procedure, you also need to set the **DELIMITER** to something other than **;**.  Below is the correct code.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE populate_wp_wpdatatable_1(x INT)
BEGIN
    SET @i = 0;
    WHILE @i < x DO
          SET @rand_value = CAST(FLOOR(RAND()*10000) as CHAR);
          INSERT INTO wp_wpdatatable_1 (jiraissue, assignee, testcasename, description, image, automation, testresult, date, status, priority, os, testtype, location, flavor) 
          VALUES 
          (CONCAT('TEST ISSUE ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('ASSIGNEE ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('TEST CASE NAME ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('DESCRIPTION ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('IMAGE ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('AUTOMATION ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('TESTRESULT ', @rand_value)
          , NOW() - INTERVAL FLOOR(RAND() * 365) DAY
          , CONCAT('STATUS ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('PRIORITY ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('OS ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('TESTTYPE ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('LOCATION ', @rand_value)
          , CONCAT('FLAVOR ', @rand_value));
          SET @i = @i + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

So yea fun stuff.  Thanks again to @Barmar for the help.